# Uiwebview navigation and redirection

Tags: uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, redirect

Any link which appears in a textview are automatically highlighted and apperas as a link and are being redirected to safari, but instead i want it to be redirected to a Uiwebview which i create for browsing. so that i won't be navigated away from my application. So how can i link my page to a uiwebview page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIWebView class (WebViewController) that loads a .xib and looks something like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *urlString;

@end
```

Then in the implementation file, implement this method:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString_];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [[self webView] loadRequest:req];
    NSLog(@"url requested");

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"showing nav");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Then in the delegate class that instantiates the web view, feed WebViewController the url and push it to the navigation controller stack:

```
netView.urlString = @"http://www.morrisjenkins.com/home";
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:netView animated:YES];
[netView release];
netView = nil;
```

(This assumes that you added the delegate class to a UINavigationController in the app's delegate)

```
UIViewController *webController = [[WebViewDelegateController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webController];
```